# registerForActivityResult doesn't work properly in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have fragment which uses camera activity. It waits data from this activity which is sent via intent. At the beginning I registered listener in the fragment:

```
private var resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
val data: Intent? = result.data

data?.let {
   val file = File(data.extras?.getString("file_path")!!)
   val uri = file.toUri()
}

}


}
```

and then after button click I launch my target activity:

```
val intent = Intent(context, CamActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("default_cam", true)
resultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

then in target activity after photo making I send data in such way:

```
val data = Intent()
data.putExtra("file_path", file.absolutePath)
setResult(RESULT_OK, data)
finish()
```

The problem is connected with processing activity results. When I open the app for the first time I can process data from the intent and enter to the `data?.let{...` block. But when I worked in some other app parts and then open this photo fragment I don't enter to `data?.let{...` block. I checked on the camera activity that photo data was sent, but my host fragment can't receive it without re-opening the app. I tried to unregister this receiver in such way:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
super.onDestroyView()
resultLauncher.unregister()
}
```

but it didn't help me.

### UPDATE

My scenario:

1. open my app with fragments A,B(here we can open cam activity) and activity C (cam activity)
2. open A -> move to B -> and press btn for camera activity (C) open
3. make some photo
4. return data from C to fragment B
5. process it in activity result contract
6. move to A (not camera fragment)
7. return to B -> press btn and open camera activity (C)
8. make photo and return data to camera fragment A
9. activity contract can't process any received data

Comment: `finishAndRemoveTask()` ?

Comment: @blackapps, fixed code blocks, yes I tried to use `finishAndRemoveTask` instead of usage finish, I thought that the problem is connected with the way of how the activity is finished

Comment: I cannot follow your scenario.

Comment: what did you mean? do you need some more context? if yes what else I can add for making solution search easier?

Comment: I dont know what exactly you are doing if you go to other apps and come back. Give an exact scenario please. Step by step instruction what to do to reproduce.

Comment: @blackapps, added instruction, can you check it pls

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the provided `intent` and set `Activity.RESULT_OK` as result when sending data from `CamActivity`:

```
intent.putExtra("file_path", file.absolutePath)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

Comment: what did you mean with provided intent? which is available in activity or what?

Comment: You should use the intent provided by the `Activity` when returning the result. For more info on `getIntent()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()

Comment: but why it works sometimes properly, but after returning to this fragment something is damaged?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact reason of it but one solution is we recreate fragment each time after we done process once.

**activity?.recreate()**

add this line where you go to another fragment from where you get image from camera or gallery.

In my case, upload an image on server after that move to previous fragment and before it add this line

`activity?.recreate()` will work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed. It should work.

```
fun openSomeActivityForResult() {
        val intent = Intent(context, CamActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("default_cam", true)
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
    
    var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            doSomeThing()
        }
    }
```

Comment: which assignment? activity result contract or what?

Comment: var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) ..... this one